# Switch baposter paper size from a0 to a1

Tags: templates, posters, baposter

I know there are multiple other questions of the same sort, however, I did not manage to get any of them to work. I am using this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bcvtznydxdzj).

I changed the document class from:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}
```

to:

```
\documentclass[a1paper,portrait]{baposter}
```

Also, I set:

```
\columnsep=70pt
\columnseprule=3pt
```

However, the layout is still not right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to adjust the `fontscale` as well:

```
\documentclass[a1paper,portrait,fontscale=0.43]{baposter}
```

The larger the `fontscale` value, the smaller the body text size is. By default *"The poster is typeset with standard font sizes on
a ‘fontscale times papersize’ paper,  and then scaled up by 1/fontscale to the chosen paper
size."*  (from the documentation at http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/).